# I need help nesting this matrix list (debug)

Tags: python, debugging

```
def ones_in_corners(n):
    '''
    Creates an nxn matrix full of 0s, except the corners of the matrix
    will have 1s in it.
    eg. ones_in_corners(3) would give us
    1 0 1
    0 0 0
    1 0 1
    :param n: the size of the square matrix
    :return:
    '''
    # setup a single row of n ' ' (space) chars
    row = ['0'] * n
    # now we will make the mat have n rows
    mat = [row] * n
    # the following four lines make it so only
    # the corners of the matrix has 1s
    mat[0][0] = '1'
    mat[0][n-1] ='1'
    mat[n-1][0] = '1'
    mat[n-1][n-1] = '1'
    return mat
```

print(ones_in_corners(3))
'''
output is [['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1']] but
I want it to be [['1', '0', '1'], ['0', '0', '0'], ['1', '0', '1']]
'''

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  This code defines a function and quits without executing.

Comment: When the function is called print(ones_in_corners(3)) the output is [['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1']] but I need it to be [['1', '0', '1'], ['0', '0', '0'], ['1', '0', '1']]

Comment: The quick answer would be, when defining matrix use `matrix = [['0'] * n for _ in range(n)` The problem lies in `row = ['0'] * n; mat = [row] * n`, here you are basically referencing original `row` n times (not creating new ones)